# Jquery scroll stops short of page bottom

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I am using jquery to scroll to sections of my page.

Here's the code:

```
// Scroll to element
$('#menu li a').click(function(){        
    var elementId = $(this).attr('href');   
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(elementId).offset().top }, 1600);
    return false;
    });

<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#item1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item2">2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="item-1">placeholder-1</div>
<div id="item-2">placeholder-2</div>
```

As you can see I'm grabbing the href (#id) of an target element from the menu link and scrolling to the target element.

But the issue lies in the fact that I have target elements going right to the bottom of the page, and when the page is scrolled to the last, the top of that element can't scroll to the top of the page as there is not enough page left at bottom... Am I making sense?

I'm trying to work out a solution using css or jquery that would mean that regardless of the height of the page (or padding/margin at bottom) the element will be at the top of the viewport when a menu item is clicked.

Do I add more padding based on the height of the viewport using javascript? Do I use some kind of overflow trick?

Comment: Can you post a live demo of this problem? Perhaps at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: Just curious, but you do know you can use `<a href="#id-of-an-element">go to that element</a>` without any javascript involved right ? Unless you need a  more specific select, just using the id is mildly bad.

Comment: @Khez I guess he want sto create the animation. `<a href="#id-of-an-element">go to that element</a>` is useful but it's not that beautiful.

Comment: @Khez: But I think Niels wants the `#id` element always at the top of the screen even if `#id` is actually at the bottom of `<body>`.

Comment: That's correct mu. I am using what Khez suggested as the fallback but prettied up with some animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the page isn't as tall as you want it to be. If you try to go to `#x` and `#x` is at the bottom of `<body>`, then you'll scroll to the bottom of the page and `#x` will be at the bottom of the window when you want it at the top.

I think your only choice is to force the `<body>` to be taller. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    viewport_height = $(window).height();
    $height_hack    = $('<div>&nbsp;</div>').height(viewport_height);
    $('body').append($height_hack);
});
```

Something like that will append a (visually) empty `<div>` to the bottom of your content, this extra `<div>` will have the same height as the browser's viewport and this extra height will let you always scroll your elements right to the top of the viewport.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution. Shame about the extraneous div but i prefer it to the scroll stopping short.

Comment: @Niels: Yeah, this is definitely a hack but at least it isn't a kludge. This is the cleanest thing I could think of to force the body to be tall enough to properly scroll.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going with this. Thanks very very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot of things you can do to solve this but I would use `CSS min-height Property` to `body`. I believe this is more a personal answer, so you can do whatever you want, as you said, add padding, margin...

But I would set a minimum height in a way the screen can scroll to the items you want it to.

---

**Update**

Hmm, right. I didn't think about dynamic content. If the content gets bigger the body minimun height will probably not solve the problem.

Comment: He wants the screen to scroll to the elements and, if I got it right, the page is not big enough. So he can use min-height to set a minimum height to the page in a way it gets big enough to the scroll thing put the item in the top of the screen.